# Store clipboard rows into variables python

Tags: python

I am using tkinter to use and bring to a python program the text that is in clipboard.
The problem is that sometimes we can have several rows, other times just one for example. How could I give to each row (if exist) a variable name?

```
The format of the data in clipboard could be:

word1
word2
word3

or

word1


or

word1
word2
word3
word4

...
```

Comment: Why dont you use a list or dict to collect the data into?

Comment: could you give me an example please. I am quite new into python. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use a list to add the elements of your clipboard into, and the you will be able to get them back by their index (row number -1)

Clipboard:

```
word1
word2
word3
```

You said something about tkinter, so i guess you can iterate over the clipboard somehow.

```
my_list = []
for element in clipboard.get(): # clipboard.get() may be different depending of the type of it
    my_list.append(element)
print my_list[1]
# print out "word2"
```

Comment: Like that it seems that is dividing the words into characters, it prints o .  not word 2.

Comment: It depends on the way you filled up the list. So try a print mehtod inside the loop to see what is put into the list. If they are words then you should get that back. Until you tell us what the clipboard really is, we cant really come up with a better solution

Comment: the print brings me the data correcly
word1
word2
word3

Comment: And if you print my_list?

Comment: ['w', 'o', 'r', 'd', '1', '\n', 'w', 'o', 'r', 'd', '2', '\n', 'w', 'o', 'r', 'd', '3']

Comment: Than the iterator should print that as well. Change the iterator to iterate over row by row and you should be good.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103700/discussion-between-gabor-erdos-and-gonzalo).